# How to hold a data during N clock cycles using DFFs?

Tags: flipflop

I want to hold a data during N clock cycles using posedge sensitive DFFs.
The timming diagram would look like:

[image]

What will be the equivalent circuit?

Thanks

Comment: Feed the DFFs with a divided clock?

Comment: It is a valid approach. Actually, the solution given below will require a clock division if enable signal is syncronous.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The way this is done is by using a D flip-flip with an enable signal. If the enable signal is brought high, the flip flop keeps it's value if the enable signal is low then it holds its value.

[image]
Source: https://www.eeweb.com/quizzes/verilog-flip-flop-with-enable-and-asynchronous-reset
Here is some pseudocode :

```
if enable== 1 then
output <=input;
else
output<=output;
end;*emphasized text*
```

Comment: Good and valid approach to the problem. If enable signal is syncronous, a clock divider will be also required. Am I wrong?

Comment: If I remember right many FPGA architectures have muxes before there memory elements. It really depends on the synthesizer.